# Interpretation of ACF plot

Tags: r, time-series

Need help on interpreting the acf plot(sin graph pattern)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

May be you will need to examine the PACF, you have a large peak in the first lag, followed by a decreasing wave that alternates between positive and negative correlations. Which can mean an autoregressive term of higher order in the data.

Use the partial autocorrelation function to determine the order of the autoregressive term.